# Meaning of $Ax \leq b$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, intuition

I continue to come across $Ax \leq b$ or $Ax= b$ in optimization problem, but I am having trouble interpreting the meaning of this. Does this have a similar meaning to the following (Cramer's Rule) from Linear Algebra?

$Ax = b \Leftrightarrow x = A^{-1} b = \frac{1}{det(A)}[adj(A)]b$

Where $A$ is a matrix and I assume $x$ and $b$ are vectors? $x$ being the solution? Essentially, this is stating give me $x$ such that $Ax$ is $\leq$ to $b$?

Comment: If $-2x = 1$ then $x = -\frac 12$.If $-2x \leq 1$, is  $x \leq -\frac 12$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember encountering the same confusion as you when presented with such inequalities in optimization problems.

$x = (x_1, \dotsc, x_n)^T$ is a column vector of variables which are usually under our control in the problem, but subject to certain constraints. For instance, you might encounter the constraint $x \geq 0$. In the vector terms you may be used to, this is not very meaningful, but in this context it means that $x$ is *entrywise* greater than $0$: Explicitly, $x_1 \geq 0, \dotsc, x_n \geq 0$. you can see why this shorthand is helpful when there are a lot of variables!

The statement $Ax \geq b$, is similarly shorthand for a system of linear inequalities with coefficients given by $A$ via usual matrix multiplication, and $b$ a fixed column vector.

For example, if
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&2\\
-1&6
\end{array}\right)$$
and $b = (2, 3)^T$, the inequality $Ax \leq b$ represents the system:

$$\begin{array}{rcrcr}
 x_1 &+& 2x_2 &\leq& 2\\
-x_1 &+& 6x_2 &\leq& 3
\end{array}$$

These inequalities specify further constraints on the variable $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$. Note that $A$ need not be a square matrix, so it will not rarely be possible to solve with equality by inverting $A$ to obtain $x = A^{-1}b$, and furthermore this is usually not useful: the aim of the problem is to extremize an expression in terms of the variables $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$, and typically only *some* of the inequalities in this system will hold with equality at an optimal solution.

Comment: By the way, some better tags for your question might be [optimization] and [intuition].

Comment: Really great answer. Thanks so much for this!

Comment: No problem; please use the 'accept answer' tick so that I can get credit for it!

Comment: I would, but cannot until i myself have 15 points. As soon as I do I'll give you credit. Thanks again.